# Email con MySQL en instancia de VM de google Cloud

Tags: mysql, email, gmail, cloud

Hola quisiera saber como seria posible hacer lo siguiente.
tengo una instancia en google cloud con una BD en MySQL, quiero que cuando una determinada tabla tenga nuevos registro envíe un correo a cada uno de los nuevos registros (ID, Nombre, email, telefono) seleccione el email y envíe un correo a cada email a traves de mi correo qu8e es de gmail con un domino propio.
gracias por todo
pls help

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.